# how to display sample rate graphically on Audio recording iphone sdk

Tags: ios

I want graphically display sound recording using AVAudioRecorder.
How to display sample rate graphically according to recording sound frequency ?
Please help.

Comment: Hardik, I'm not sure what you want to do. Surely, the sample rate will be fixed during recording?